# update-database System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

We have been using code first migrations for about a year now, works great, lots of migrations. suddenly this week it stopped working. 
I'm running update-database or add-Migration and getting a "Sequence contains no matching element"

```
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<GetStoreAssociationTypePairs>d__70.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__22`3.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__63`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.FindAssociationTypePairs(ICollection`1 entityTypePairs)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Sequence contains no matching element
PM>
```

Comment: I've also deleted the migration folder and tried enable-migrations (no error) then add-Migration again and the same error message happens.

Comment: We have about 400+ migrations so far.

Comment: Also, all the migrations in my migrations folder are in the  __MigrationHistory table.

Comment: what was your latest model change ? can you share that code ?

Comment: Use update-database -Script to generate a script. Inspect or run that to see what's bombing.

Comment: I do believe you are using a .HasColumnType with a type the DBMS does not know (or wrong syntax). There it will select the matching type with a .Single statement upon model creation, which would result in this exception.

Answer (score 4):

Did an add-Migration - IgnoreChanges and its working now. 
the change didn't affect the schema so the migration would have been blank anyway.